# Trazer mais de uma linha em uma SubQuery Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com 2 consultas e gostaria de uma forma de unir as 2 em uma, porém estou com dificuldades.

Tenho o Seguinte Exemplo:

Tabela T1:

```
  CD    PF        Data           Total
  1     JSL001    15/03/2018     100
```

Tabela T2:

```
  ID    PF      Data        Motivo  Total
  45    JSL001  15/03/2018  X       85 
  46    JSL001  15/03/2018  Y       15
```

Preciso montar uma consulta em que eu tenha os valores da T1 complementados pelos valores da T2 usando como fator comparativo o campo de Data e PF,

Desta forma o resultado esperado seria o seguinte:

```
  CD    PF      Data         Total  T2.Motivo   T2.Total
  1    JSL001   15/03/2018   100     X          85 
  1    JSL001   15/03/2018   100     Y          15
```

Eu tentei com Subqueryes, porém quando retorna mais de uma linha ele não aceita, também não consegui implementar um UNION pra isso.

> Estou usando o SQL Server 2014

Comment: Qual a relação entre as tabelas?

Answer (score 1):

Por que não usando `join`?

```
select t1.CD, t1.PF, t1.Data, t1.Total,
       t2.Motivo, t2.Total
  from t1 inner join t2 on t1.pf = t2.pf
```

Pelo que você mostrou, o campo que liga as tabelas é `PF`, então basta um `inner join` para trazer o resultado que você precisa.

Se a Data também fizer parte do condição, melhor usar o `where`, assim:

```
select t1.CD, t1.PF, t1.Data, t1.Total,
       t2.Motivo, t2.Total
  from t1, t2 
 where t1.pf = t2.pf 
   and t1.Data = t2.Data
```

Comment: Na segunda consulta, não precisa usar o Where, é so acrescentar o AND no JOIN.

Comment: Sim é verdade @EmanuelF, é que costumo usar o `join` para campos "chave", a data não me parece ser, por isso acho que no `where` fica mais claro, mas só uma opção pessoal mesmo :)

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar simplesmente o INNER JOIN. Segue o exemplo no SQL Fiddle [AQUI](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a971/2)

```
SELECT T1.*, 
        T2.Motivo AS MotivoT2, 
        T2.Total AS TotalT2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.PF = T1.PF
```

Comment: não é a mesma coisa que eu já havia respondido?

Comment: Sugestão: acrescente a coluna Data na cláusula ON.

Answer (score 0):

> *Preciso montar uma consulta em que eu tenha os valores da T1 complementados pelos valores da T2 usando como fator comparativo o campo de Data e PF*

A solução, como já comentado em outras respostas, está na junção entre as tabelas T1 e T2.

Eis solução que utiliza LEFT OUTER JOIN e utiliza as duas colunas mencionadas acima para estabelecer a ligação entre as tabelas.

```
-- código #1
SELECT T1.CD, T1.PF, T1.Data, T1.Total,
       T2.Motivo as [T2.Motivo], T2.Total as [T2.Total]
  from T1
       left join T2 on T1.PF = T2.PF
                       and T1.Data = T2.Data;
```